# Is there anything to be gained by using 'folders' in an s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am moving a largish number of jpgs (several hundred thousand) from a static filesystem to amazon s3.

On the old filesytem, I grouped files into subfolders to keep the total number of files / folder manageable.

For example, a file

```
4aca29c7c0a76c1cbaad40b2693e6bef.jpg
```

would be saved to:

```
/4a/ca/29/4aca29c7c0a76c1cbaad40b2693e6bef.jpg
```

From what I understand, s3 doesn't respect hierarchial namespaces.  So if I were to use 'folders' on s3, the object, including the /'s, would really just be in a flat namesapce.

Still, according to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/organize-s3.html), amazon recommends mimicking a structured filesytem when working with s3.

So I am wondering:  Is there anything to be gained using the above folder structure to organize files on s3?  Or in this case am I better off just adding the files to s3 without any kind of 'folder' structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "folders" has no performance impact on S3, either way.  It doesn't make it faster, and it doesn't make it slower.

The value of delimiting your object keys with `/` is in organization, both machine-friendly and human-friendly.

If you're trolling through a bucket in the console, troubleshooting, those meaningless noise-filled keys are a hassle to paginate through, only a few dozen at a time.

The console automatically groups objects into imaginary folders based on the `/` delimiters, so you can find your object to inspect it (check headers, metadata, etc.) is much easier if you can just click on `4a` then `ca` then `29`.

The S3 ListObjects APIs support requesting all the objects with a certain key prefix, but they also support finding all the common prefixes before the next delimiter, so you can send API requests to list prefix `4a/ca/` with delimiter `/` and it will *only* return the "folders" one level deep, which it refers to as "common prefixes."

This is less meaningful if your object keys are fully opaque and convey nothing more about the objects, as opposed to using key prefixes like `images/` and `thumbnails/` and `videos/`.

Having been an admin and working with S3 for a number of years, and having worked with buckets with key naming schemes designed by different teams, I would definitely recommend using some `/` delimiters for organization purposes.  The buckets without them become more of a hassle to navigate over time.

Note that the console does allow you to "create folders," but this is more of the illusion -- there is no need to actually do this, unless you're loading a bucket manually.  When you create a folder in the console, it just creates an empty object with a `/` at the end.

Comment: My understanding is that S3 hashes object keys, so that lookup time for a given object is O(1). But what is the expected time for a call to AmazonS3.listObjects that match a prefix? The documentation for AmazonS3.listObjects says "The total number of keys in a bucket doesn't substantially affect list performance." But how is that possible unless they index prefixes of keys? I asked AWS engineers for more guidance and they dodged the question and just said that calling listObjects can be slow. I suspect S3 does a linear search through the entire bucket to find objects matching a prefix.

Comment: @DonSmith I have never heard that S3 hashes object keys.  Do you have a source for that?  I have always assumed it was a sharded B-tree since it the exposed  API and previously-generation best practices documents seem to imply that. In fact, my working assumption is that it's a B-tree of (bucket + / + key) with sequentially-named buckets potentially being in the same index shard.  I have never found ListObjects to be slow, certainly not slow enough to imply a full scan, though my biggest buckets typically have object counts only in the low millions.

Comment: Amazon _used_ to recommend prepending a random or varying string to keys, to improve performance: to better distribute objects in partitions/buckets.  That suggests that they use(d) hashing.   They no longer recommend prepending:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html .  Perhaps they *do* use b-trees or some such O(log(n)) data structure; if so, then, presumably, listObjects by prefix would be fast.   The AWS documentation is vague about how it works. Perhaps it's just super-parallelized.  Knowing expected performance would guide our use of it.

Comment: @DonSmith I would argue that the former recommendation of prepending random strings was an indication of exactly the opposite -- it suggests that they they *didn't* hash the keys, because there would be no need to randomize values (hashing would handle that).  What they were specifically recommending against was sequential or constantly-incrementing object keys with a common prefix -- like the current date and time -- which would cause a hot spot in a B-tree (or any lexically sorted structure) that can't be fixed by sharding, but would be a non-issue if the keys were already being hashed.

Comment: According to https://minops.com/blog/2015/01/aws-s3-performance-tuning/, S3 used to use the first several characters of the key in the hash function.

Answer (score 2):

Performance is **not impacted** by the use (or non-use) of folders.

Some systems can use folders for **easier navigation** of the files. For example, Amazon Athena can scan specific sub-directories when querying data rather than having to read every file.

If your bucket is being used for one specific purpose, there is no reason to use folders. However, if it contains different types of data, then you might consider at least a **top-level set of folders** to keep data separated.

Another potential reason for using folders is for **security**. A bucket policy can grant access to buckets based upon a prefix (which is a folder name). However, this is likely not relevant for your use-case.

Comment: Another instance where folders can help is while using S3 triggers. I wanted to invoke different lambda functions for different files, it was easy to apply them on separate folders like s3://bucket/folderA/ triggers functionA and s3://bucket/folderB triggers functionB. If the files arrived at the same location, in the bucket, s3://bucket/ the trigger would launch both lambdas for every new file that arrived. PS: The files had identical naming convention and extensions, so it was not possible to distinguish them using suffix.

Comment: Re "performance is not impacted": this is not strictly true. Per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html#workloads-with-mix-request-types), if you have high request rates then randomness at the leading edge of the object key will allow more efficient distribution. Although, as noted in that same document, this will only affect you if you have sustained request rates > 100 per second.

Comment: The randomness can be either in the filename or the prefix (folder name).

Comment: @kdgregory This is no longer the case: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/amazon-s3-announces-increased-request-rate-performance/

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Per its URL, that blog post was written in July of 2018. My comment was written in February of 2018. There's no need to me to tell me that it's out-of-date.

Comment: @kdgregory I wrote it for future readers so they not be mislead.